# Is it possible to get results/crosstables from USCF-rated events before 1990?

Tags: tournament, uscf

In my school days in the early 1980's I played in a few USCF-rated tournaments. Once school was over, I dropped out of tournament play and even dropped my USCF membership.

Now, to support my child who is playing in tournaments, I've re-joined USCF. I see that crosstables for tournaments seem to be available going back to 1990. Is it possible to get results from tournaments before then? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

I personally doubt it, since those were early computer days when I don't think that much of that information could be easily stored long term. I would however suggest contacting the USCF for definitive information. They have moved their headquarters since then, from NY to Tennessee, but it's possible that some records may have survived.

USCF Telephone:  (888) 512-4377 (CHESS)

Customer Support
Monday through Friday - 9:00 A.M. until 5:00 P.M. (Central)

Facsimile: 256.851.0560

Electronic Mail: customerservice@uscfsales.com

Comment: Note that they've moved again. They are in St. Louis now. (Although from what I understand much of their work is now done remotely.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the tournament directors from those tournaments are still around and still have those records, but if so, contacting them might be the way to go.

Comment: Good idea, although I have no idea how to contact them ... or even who some of them were. I suspect some have passed away by now.

Comment: TD's tend to know other TD's; if you ask one from the area who has been around a while, they might know.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out your rating even if you last played before 1990.  I played 2 tournaments in 1985 and they still had record of my rating when I resumed play after 2000.

Comment: Where can one find it? Otherwise this is rather useless

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you can get that information?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, it's easy enough to find your rating on the US Chess web site after you reactivate your account. However, that's not what I was asking about. I would like to know if I can get records of who I played in a tournament and the results of those match ups.

Answer (score 0):

Those records definetly still exist. I would suggest contacting the US Chess Federation, since they definetly have them. Whether you'll be able to get them is a different story.